# Node.js Server Crashing

Tags: node.js, websocket

I run my server using the command

```
node server.js
```

It runs as expected but it crashes randomly, I think it's when the server is idle (looking at the server message after it crashes).

I was hoping someone could tell me whats actually happening, the log: http://pastebin.com/2scYNq1M

the server.js: http://pastebin.com/XVYs8VwN

Comment: We need waaaaay more information to even begin to answer this. Please include the code from server.js at the very least.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the log file would indicate the reason - I have included my server.js file. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `wsServer.on('error', ...` and `connection.on('error', ...` handlers.

I suspect that there is an error happening somewhere, but since you don't have an error handler, it just crashes because of it.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the advice